# C# Capture webrequest request via json and Serializer into c# object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, webrequest

I am communicating to a restful API and trying to capture the response via a c# object.

I have successfully captured response previously using WebRequest and Get, but using Post and Streamreader I think that I am making some silly mistake.

I would appreciate if somebody could help me to identify the correct structure for my JavaScriptSerializer and also am I requesting the information correctly to capture a Json object ?

EDIT: I should note my apologies - I receive an error on the Serialize code of "Invalid JSON primitive: ." <-- I am clutching at straws but is the full stop at the end of the Message causing the fall over ?

```
         public void UpdatePosition(string SessionID, int AssetID, string SerialNumber)
    {
        positions Positions = GeneratePositions(AssetID);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://some.website.com/webservices/command/v1/Position?Session=" + SessionID + "&Serial=" + SerialNumber + "&Positions=" + Positions.Latitude + "," + Positions.Longitude + "," + Positions.SpeedKmh + "," + Positions.Course + "," + Positions.Utcdatetime + "," + Positions.IgnitionState);

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Reply2 info = new Reply2();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer parser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            info = parser.Deserialize<Reply2>(result);
        }

        return;
    }            

    public class UpdatePostionResponse
    {
        public responseCode ResponseCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reply2
    {
        public  UpdatePostionResponse response { get; set; }
    }

        public class responseCode
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Using Postman I get success but can not capture the response correctly.
Response :

```
<UpdatePostionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<ResponseCode xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Command.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:Code>UpdatePositionSuccess</a:Code>
    <a:Message>Positions updated.</a:Message>
</ResponseCode>
```

Comment: The service is responding in XML not json and is ignoring your accept header. Would need to know more about the service to say more.

Comment: @PaulSwetz Thank you Paul, at least it provides me with an avenue to pursue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out exactly as Paul Swetz pointed out, the server was not returning json but XML only.

Thank you to Paul for highlighting this and thanks to POSTMAN for helping me to identify and show to server coders to get it corrected.